# Odd characters in output

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple hangman game in c++ by randomly selecting a word from a list, checking the string length, and writing that many *s into a new string to serve as placeholders in the yet un-guessed word.  The max length is 9 letters.  I have the game working almost flawlessly -- the problem is that whenever my word has 8 or 9 letters, the program prints the correct number of *s followed by one or two � characters.  Research tells me these are unprintable characters, but I've tried for a while now and I'm not sure why they're here, why they only show up with a word length>7, or how to get rid of them.  Below is relevant code.  Any suggestions?

Generating *s:

```
char word[80];
int len=strlen(targetWord);
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    word[i]='*';
}
```

Comment: [NUL-terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Comment: You aren't showing all of the relevant code here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `\0` terminator at the end of the string.  After the `for` loop, add:

```
word[i] = '\0';
```

Or, best, use `std::string` instead of a C string.

Comment: Thanks a lot…never thought to manually end it like that.  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `std::string` instead.

```
std::string word;
int len=strlen(targetWord);
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    word+='*';
}
```